# Get records of last week adding by datetime in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using asp.net MVC in my project. My database table includes some records. The table has datetime column for records. I want to get records of last week adding. So the `LastlyRecords` is:

```
DateTime.Now = 04.04.2015
LastWeekDateTime = 28.04.2015
LastWeekDateTime < LastlyRecords < DateTime.Now
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a method that accepts a "Start Date" and "End Date" as parameters.

Call it with a start/end date like:

```
GetRecords(DateTime.Now.AddWeeks(-1), DateTime.Now);
```

For there, you can have a stored procedure fetch records between that date range (or do something similar for Entity Framework or whatever you're using).

You can do something similar in T-SQL via GETDATE() and DATEADD(), but it's arguably better to do the range calculation in the calling code (because it's more a business logic thing than a data access thing).

Comment: In my table the dateTime column has string value. I'm getting day of dateTime with split and comparing the `DateTime.Today.AddDays((int)-7).Day` but when the my dateTime is for example, `3` and now date is `4`. 4-7 = 28. Is not  28<3<4 numerically, although it is true?

Comment: I'd highly recommend changing your database table to use a date type instead of a date string. Not doing so would be a significant design flaw that will hurt performance and complicate your code.

Answer (score 0):

you have to write logic on your query or you can modify below as per your datetime range.

```html
var lastweek = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);

var records = d in db.Persons 
              where DateTime.Compare(lastweek, d.DateRecordColumn) 
              and  DateTime.Compare(d.DateRecordColumn, DateTime.Now)
              select d;
```

hope this help to resolve your query!!!

Comment: `var week = Person.Where(x =>
                                        Int32.Parse(x.dateTime.Split(' ').ElementAt(0)) <= DateTime.Now.Day &&
                                        Int32.Parse(x.dateTime.Split(' ').ElementAt(0)) > DateTime.Today.AddDays((int)-7).Day &&
                                        x.dateTime.Split(' ').ElementAt(1).ToString() == DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM") &&
                                        Int32.Parse(x.dateTime.Split(' ').ElementAt(2)) == DateTime.Now.Year)`My last week query is it but has error when `LastWeekDay > DateTime.Now.Day` MyTime`04 April 2015`

Comment: what error you getting? i believe you need to play on this only. as your date is in string format.

Comment: its actually the way you stored your date in table as string. can you try this on sql side itself and use same logic i provided and convert your datestring field to date type before compare then you will be able to compare properly. CONVERT(DATETIME, datetimeColumn, XXX) > GETDATE()

Answer (score 0):

```
string dateTime = "01 April 2015 Wednesday 16:23";
DateTime time1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime);

if (DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, time1) == 1 &&  // DateTime.Now > time1
    DateTime.Compare(time1, DateTime.Today.AddDays((int)-7)) == 1 // time1 >= DateTime.Now-7days
    )
{
    @("True.")
}
else
{
    @("False.")
}
```

The result is true, so it is in last week.